# Mysql query - GROUP BY and show the highest COUNT(*)

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a small project and I'm trying to get the restaurant with the most votes each week to be displayed once.

[image: Screen of database]

This is my query:

```
SELECT votedRestaurant,
       week,
       COUNT(*)
FROM mylunch.votes
GROUP BY votedRestaurant,
         week
ORDER BY week DESC;
```

This gets me the following result:

[image: Screen of returned]

I would only like to have the one with the highest COUNT(*) displayed per week.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: No pictures, thanks. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Mysql 8 you can make use of window functions

```
WITH
  cte AS  (SELECT votedRestaurant, WEEK, COUNT(*) total
            FROM votes 
            GROUP BY votedRestaurant,WEEK 
            ORDER BY WEEK DESC, votedRestaurant)
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT *,
    row_number() over (PARTITION BY WEEK ORDER BY total DESC) AS rn
FROM 
    cte
 ) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/egfshE2YkYgRuQnzh9HNT8/0)

Another way would be by using string fuctions

```
SELECT t.week, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t.votedRestaurant ORDER BY t.total DESC),',',1) votedRestaurant, MAX(t.total)
FROM(
    SELECT votedRestaurant, WEEK, COUNT(*)  total
    FROM votes 
    GROUP BY votedRestaurant,WEEK 
    ORDER BY WEEK DESC
) t
GROUP BY t.week
ORDER BY t.week DESC
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/egfshE2YkYgRuQnzh9HNT8/2)

Comment: Thank you, the second one works like a charm. The version i'm using is 6.3

Answer (score 1):

you can try use [LIMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html) and ordering by count, for example

```
      SELECT votedRestaurant,
           week,
           COUNT(*) AS tcount
    FROM mylunch.votes
    GROUP BY votedRestaurant,
             week
    ORDER BY tcount DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

Also, you can use subquery, so says the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-row.html).